# Write down the partial fraction of $\frac{3x^2+1}{(x+1)\left(x-5\right)^2}$.

Tags: partial-fractions

One such decomposition is:
$$
\dfrac{A}{x+1} + \dfrac{B}{x-5} + \frac{C}{\left(x-5\right)^2}.
$$

Why can't we decompose like below?

$$
\dfrac{A}{x+1} + \dfrac{B}{(x-5)^2}
$$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. Please try to use [MathJax syntax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset equations inside your questions. This makes them easier to read for everyone.

Comment: the correct two piece version is $$
\frac{A}{x+1} + \frac{Bx +D}{(x-5)^2}
$$

Comment: Ok. But my question was why does the above decomposition fails. ?

Comment: Try it!  That is, $$\frac{3x^2+1}{(x+1)(x-5)^2}=\frac{A}{x+1} + \frac{B}{(x-5)^2}.$$  Get common denominator.  You get a system of linear equations to solve for $A,B$ (three equations in two unknowns).  There is no solution!  So that decomposition fails.

Comment: A(x-5)^2 + B(x+1) = 3x^2 + 1 . We can plug in x = 5 and -1 and get A, B right ? Please correct me if i am wrong

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we rewrite the putative decomposition
$$\frac{A}{x + 1} + \frac{B}{(x - 5)^2}$$
in standard form:
$$\frac{A x^2 + (-10 A + B) x + (25 A + B)}{(x + 1) (x - 5)^2} .$$
Comparing coefficients of the numerator shows that any rational function $$\frac{a x^2 + b x + c}{(x + 1) (x - 5)^2}$$ that can be written in the form $\frac{A}{x + 1} + \frac{B}{(x - 5)^2}$ must satisfy $35 a + b - c = 0$, which not all of them do.

Heuristically, for a fixed denominator $q(x)$, a proper rational expression $\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$ is specified by $n := \deg q$ parameters, namely, the coefficients $p_0, \ldots, p_{n - 1}$ of $p(x)$. So, we expect that generically a partial fraction decomposition will need to be specified by $n$ parameters. In our case, $\deg ((x + 1) (x - 5)^2) = 3$, so we expect to need $3$ parameters rather than $2$. One way to rectify this situation is to write
$$\frac{ax^2 + b x + c}{(x + 1)(x - 5)^2} = \frac{A}{x + 1} + \frac{B}{x - 5} + \frac{C}{(x - 5)^2} ,$$ which turns out to determine $A, B, C$ uniquely.

Comment: It helped! Thanks